# Maneiras de checar se existe algum software de captura de tela em execução com C#

Tags: c#, captura-de-tela

Estou desenvolvendo um software escrito em C# de exibição de vídeos pagos e preciso criar proteções para evitar ao máximo que os compradores distribuam os vídeos de forma irregular.

Por agora preciso evitar que softwares de captura estejam em execução. A única alternativa que tive foi criar um hook nas rotinas do Windows que são responsáveis por fornecer essa captura e fazer checagens periódicas, porém não encontrei materiais sobre como fazer isso.

Quais outras alternativas ao alcance da plataforma .Net que posso utilizar para saber se existe algum software em execução que esteja capturando a tela?

Answer (score 3):

Não quero ser pessimista, mas é quase impossível saber/prevenir execuções de software de captura de tela, você pode criar uma lista enorme de softwares conhecidos de captura e fazer com que seu software faça acesso a lista de processos em execução do windows, você simplesmente vai comparar qual processo bate com sua lista de softwares de captura "indesejados".

Ou fazer com que seu software acesse a lista de aplicativos instalados no windows e ver se algum nome bate com sua lista conhecida. caso você tenha uma resposta positiva cabe a você dar um alerta para o usuário ou simplesmente não reproduzir o vídeo.

Para barrar completamente coisas deste tipo você teria que praticamente reescrever o driver de vídeo, ou seja barrar literalmente na origem!

Lembrando que você ainda corre o risco do cara simplesmente pegar um celular/camera/filmadora e gravar.

Para minimizar você pode carimbar seus vídeos com uma marca d'água (watermark), se o vídeo vazar ele vai ter o logo da sua empresa, hoje em dia eu sei que algumas empresas renderizam marcas no momento do stream com modificações sutis para cada usuário, a olho nú todas as marcas parecem iguais, mas quando aplicado métodos de fingerprint(impressão digital) no vídeo vazado é possível rastrear por essa marca qual usuário foi o responsável.

Você pode tentar acessar as hot keys do windows pela sua aplicação e tentar desabilitar as teclas de captura de tela, veja um exemplo de como registrar e desabilitar a captura de print screen usando C# [aqui](http://maruf-dotnetdeveloper.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/c-how-to-register-hotkeys-in-windows.html), se algum software de captura utilizar essa mesma hot key para efetuar captura não vai mais funcionar, mas infelizmente você vai ter pouco sucesso, a grande maioria dos programas de captura definem seus próprios hot keys é quase como dar um tiro no escuro.

Comment: Legal, já vi também que é possível incluir assinaturas inaudíveis no áudio mas que podem ser lidas digitalmente e rastrear a origem do vazamento.

Comment: Yeah com áudio eu já fiz rsrs

Comment: Não vou entrar em detalhes mas se reduzindo 40% da distribuição indevida dos vídeos já é algo positivo pra mim. Ja pensei em verificar os processos com uma lista de nomes pre estabelecidos mas existem muitos softwares do gênero. Deve haver um jeito a baixo nivel de fazer essa checagem.

Comment: olha o que escrevi sobre hot keys ...

Comment: Na verdade estou preocupado é com a captura de vídeo. Andei pesquisando algumas rotinas da win32 API que conseguem fazer algum reconhecimento, porém com o FRAPS por exemplo não adiantou. O jeito é bolar algum algoritmo e tentar ofuscar o máximo que puder. Tenho algo me mente, comento aqui assim que testar.

Comment: As hot keys de print são usadas por alguns programas para fazer videos, se desabilitar essas teclas alguns programas não vão capturar frames via essas teclas e não vai gerar videos, mas isso não vai funcionar para todos ...

Comment: Mesmo com todas essas proteções, você não tem como impedir que o usuário crie uma máquina virtual. E capture a tela a partir da máquina hospedeira.